# Variables names ambiguity in C++

Tags: c++, ambiguous

I'm a bit confused at this situation:

```
#include <iostream>

void function(int origin)
{
    if (origin < 0)
    {
        double origin = 0.3;

        std::cout << origin << std::endl;
    }
}

int main()
{
    function(-4);
}
```

where it gets compiled and run successfully using VS2013 under v120 ToolSet. Isn't it wrong C++? 'Cause doing the same but just in the beginning of function it gives a compile-time error.

Comment: This isn't the issue, but don't use `std::endl` unless you need the extra stuff that it does. `'\n'` ends a line.

Comment: @PeteBecker wow, an advice from a guru can't be avoided ;) and I never thought there are some differences between **::endl** and **'\n'**. will go through some references about it. thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't mind this C++ behaviour. Sure, it can lead to bugs/oversights as you have demonstrated. But you can do this in C++

```
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; ++i) {
        cout << i;
    }
    cout << i;
}
cout << endl;
for (int i = 0; i < 4; ++i) {
    for (int j = 0; j < 5; ++j) {
        cout << j;
    }
    cout << i;
}
```

and the results are identical because `i` is redefined in the scope of the inner `for` loop to be a different variable.

In other languages like C# you can't do this. It will tell you have tried to redeclare a variable of the same name in an inner scope.

I find this over-protective. When I'm cutting and pasting code with loops, it is irritating to have to redeclare `i`, which we all tend to use as the loop variable, to be `i1`, `i2` etc. I invariably miss one, with cut-and-paste code, so I'm using `arr[i]` in an `i3` loop, when I meant `arr[i3]` (whoops).

In production code, I agree that defensive coding means you should use different names for loop variables in the same function.

But it's nice to be able to reuse variable names in nested for loops when you're experimenting. C++ gives you that choice.

Answer (score 2):

This is legal according to C++ standard, section 3.3.3.1:

> A name declared in a block is local to that block; it has block scope. Its potential scope begins at its point of declaration and ends at the end of its block. A variable declared at block scope is a local variable.

Such redeclaration hides the `origin` parameter.

> Cause doing the same but just in the beginning of function it gives a compile-time error.

You get an error because C++ standard explicitly disallows such redeclaration in section 3.3.3.2:

> A parameter name shall not be redeclared in the outermost block of the function definition nor in the outermost block of any handler associated with a function-try-block.

The reason for this exclusion is that function parameters are local to the outer scope of the function, so having a redeclaration without another layer of braces would introduce a duplicate identifier into the same scope.

Answer (score 1):

> Isn't it wrong C++?

No. It's perfectly legal to redeclare an identifier, as long as it's in a different scope. In this case, the scope is the then-body of the if-statement.

It isn't ambiguous. The nearest preceding declaration will be used.

Comment: While it's valid, it's not generally recommended as it can lead to bugs.

Answer (score 1):

No, it is not wrong. It is a perfectly valid behavior according to the standard.

```
void function(int origin)
{
    if (origin < 0) // scope of the first 'origin'
    {
        double origin = 0.3; // scope of the second 'origin' begins
                             // scope of the first 'origin' is interrupted

        std::cout << origin << std::endl;
    } //block ends, scope of the second 'origin' ends
      //scope of the first 'origin' resumes
}
```

As tupe_cat said it is always valid to redeclare if their scopes vary. In such cases variable belonging to the inner scope will gain over the outer scope.